# Prove that the time-derivative of relativistic momentum is equal to the Lorentz force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus

In exercise 5.6 of QFT for the Gifted Amateur, the book wants me prove that for a particle in an electromagnetic field, which has the Lagrangian:
$$L=-\frac{mc^{2}}{γ}+q{\bf A}\cdot{\bf v}-qV$$
The derivative of its relativistic momentum will be equal to the Lorentz force,
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\gamma m{\bf v})=q({\bf E}+{\bf v}\times{\bf B}).$$
I have no clue how to arrive at this conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a homework question, then these are hints. You need to use the  Euler-Langrange equation $$\tag 1\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0$$

where $\dot{\vec x} = \vec v$. So first take the derivative, $$\tag 2\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot x}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial v}=\gamma mv + q\vec A$$

Next take the derivative $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=q(\vec  v \times \vec B - \nabla V)$$ If you take the time derivative of (2) and put all this back into equation (1), you should get something like

$$\frac{d(\gamma mv)}{dt}=\vec F$$ where $\vec F$ is the Lorentz force.

Comment: Thankyou, for your answer, although I'm confused as to how the x-derivative of the Lagrangian evaluates to what you have. I applied some vector calculus identities, and came to the conclusion that (v∙∇)A=0, for it to reduce to the expression you had.

Comment: Actually, if you evaluated the derivative correctly, you would find two terms $(A · ∇)v + (v · ∇)A$ and another term $A \times ∇ \times v$ that vanish, leaving the terms $v \times ∇ \times A = v\times B$ and $\nabla V$. Only these last two terms survive, which should give your answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, my problem is why does the term  (v∙∇)A vanish?

Comment: OK, one more hint. There are vector triple cross product identities. Cheers.

Comment: Also, I'm learning QFT by myself, I'm not getting homework from anybody.

Comment: No problems. Good luck with that. Cheers.

Comment: I figured out the question, it turns out I accidentally treated the total time-derivative of the vector potential as the partial time-derivative, thus leading to the confusion about (v∙∇)A.

Comment: I see. I'm glad you worked it out. Well done!